# For Blender 2.80 API, What replaces the constraint_orientation parameter in bpy.ops.transform?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to update [my plug-in](https://github.com/bastianilso/blender-csv-importer) from Blender 2.79 code. I am getting the following error from Blender:

```
TypeError: Converting py args operator properties: keyword "constraint_orientation" unrecognized.
```

[image: Screenshot of Blender constraint_orientation error]

The code relates to [this call](https://github.com/bastianilso/blender-csv-importer/blob/master/__init__.py#L584) in `__init__.py`:

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 1.5, 0), constraint_axis=(False, True, False), constraint_orientation='LOCAL')
```

What is the right way create such a constraint in Blender 2.80?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.transform.html#bpy.ops.transform.translate)?

Comment: Also, you might want to look into using matrix_world translations instead of call bpy.ops.transform.translate. You can create a trans_local variable Vector for the translation, combine the local translation with the world matrix with obj.matrix_world.to_3x3() @ trans_local, and the translate with obj.matrix_world.translation += trans_world. Might be a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace constraint_orientation with orient_type.

Links aren't ideal because they might die. If there is a way to add this more permanently, please let me know.

https://blenderartists.org/t/2-80-cheat-sheet-for-updating-add-ons/1148974

[image]