# How do I run a function from a custom script from the Python Console?

Tags: python, scripting

I found a script with an instruction to run it, but it doesn't work for me. Script is working for other people but if I run it the way it's described I only get errors.

It says:

> Just copy the code into a new file on blender's text editor, call the
> text file apply_with_shape_keys.py, and then, select the object with
> the modifiers and shape keys, (make a backup, just in case). Now from
> the console execute it like this:
>
> `import apply_with_shape_keys`
>
> `apply_with_shape_keys.super_apply_modifiers()`

My results:

```
>>> import apply_with_shape_keys
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apply_with_shape_keys'
```

The script text is named apply_with_shape_keys.py

The script:

```
import bpy

def reset_shape_keys ():    
    for name, shape_key in get_active_block().items():
        shape_key.value = 0

def get_active_block ():
    block_id = bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.id_data.name
    return bpy.data.shape_keys[block_id].key_blocks

def select (selection):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    selection.select = True
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = selection

def select_last_shape_key ():
    shape_key_count = len(get_active_block().items())
    bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = shape_key_count - 1

def remove_shape_keys (object):
    selection = bpy.context.object
    select(object)
    shape_key_count = len(get_active_block().items())
    select_last_shape_key()
    for i in range(0, shape_key_count):
        bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=False)
    select(selection)

def apply_modifiers (object):
    selection = bpy.context.object
    select(object)

    for key, modifier in object.modifiers.items():
        if key != 'Armature':
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier=key)

    select(selection)        

def super_apply_modifiers ():
    original = bpy.context.object
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0), "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED', "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})
    backup = bpy.context.object
    backup.name = 'backup'
    remove_shape_keys(original)
    apply_modifiers(original)

    for key, shape_key in get_active_block().items():
        select(backup)
        bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0), "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED', "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})

        meshed_shape_key = bpy.context.object
        select(meshed_shape_key)
        reset_shape_keys()
        get_active_block()[key].value = 1
        bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')

        select(original)
        meshed_shape_key.select = True
        bpy.ops.object.join_shapes()
        select_last_shape_key()
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key.name = key

        select(meshed_shape_key)
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
```

How do I get it working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This has changed**

Being able to import py suffixed text editor scripts by name is no longer available in blender 2.8+

Instead of importing, use  the `Text.as_module()` method to return script as  a module like object.

For example, copying script from question, pasting into text editor, naming it "Foo"

Python console test:

```
>>> foo = D.texts['Foo'].as_module()
>>> foo.
        apply_modifiers(
        bpy
        get_active_block(
        remove_shape_keys(
        reset_shape_keys(
        select(
        select_last_shape_key(
        super_apply_modifiers(
```

Comment: The second command is confusing. Do you mean I need to call
 "foo.super_apply_modifiers()"?

Comment: The beauty of the python console is .. give it a try to confirm   When you type `foo.<TAB>` Iwhere tab is the tab key) into blenders interactive python console it autocompletes.  Result of autocomplete is shown. showing the members of the text editor module `foo`

Comment: Can't find the autocompletion but the functions do seem to run, thanks. However there are errors probably unrelated to the topic that I now need to get sorted

TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "constraint_orientation" unrecognized

Comment: On prior version <ctrl><space> is autocomplete. Simply look at the console menu. IIRC constraint_orientation is a version issue too. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166397/for-blender-2-80-api-what-replaces-the-constraint-orientation-parameter-in-bpy

Comment: @user3024701  also any value passed to an operator that is default need not be passed to the operator.  Most operators in question code could be replaced with API methods, eg `bpy.data.objects.remove(meshed_shape_key)` removes the object

Comment: With the new foo.as_module() function, is there an import all option? So there is no need to prefix every function in foo with `foo.` in the script? @batFINGER